# SCroll position In javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've 3 accodion sections In the form and each contains 10 elements, whenever I've error on any field scroll position should move to that element or If we have multiple errors then It should go to the First error In the form.

Comment: Show some HTML code

Comment: You may want to look at [asking effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), SO is here to help you debug but you should show a minimal repeatable example of what you have tried and the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

with try and catch you can catch the error and scroll to the position you want.
You can do it with

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```